# Do you recognize this theme

Tags: wordpress, drupal, templates, themes

I'm working on a project and my client gave me this theme as a guideline to what he wanted. I can build something similar but I remember seeing this theme before so I think it's a template. Can someone recognize it?

[image: http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/9049/screenshot088d.jpg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it comes with Apple's [iWeb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IWeb) software.